# Setting a title to a UIToolBar in IOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a UIToolBar button declared below:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64.0);
```

I also have a UIBarButtonItem that gets added in on the left as a back button.  But how do I just add a centered label title to the UIToolbar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 150, 20)];
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[self.view addSubview:lblTitle];
UIBarButtonItem *typeField = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:lblTitle];   
toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:backButton,spaceBar,lblTitle, nil]];
```

This will solve your problem i think.

Answer (score 7):

Create a UILabel and add it as an item of the toolbar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *toolBarTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myLabel];
```

If you want to center it, add flexible spaces on the sides:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]
```

Comment: I have this as the label:  UILabel *errorLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 140.0, 125.0) ]; but the y property of the rect isn't working right

Comment: Your toolbar is 64 height, andf your label starts at 100, you need to change the y.

Comment: yeah but the UILabel text is off compared to my UIBarButtonItem back Button.  How do I move the UILabel text down the page

Comment: Add some y if you want, but not 100! That goes beyond the toolbar

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers were as copy and pasteable as I wanted, so...

```
UILabel *toolbarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
toolbarLabel.text = @"Text in yo toolbar";
[toolbarLabel sizeToFit];
toolbarLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
toolbarLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
toolbarLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
UIBarButtonItem *labelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toolbarLabel];
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[self setToolbarItems:@[flexible, labelItem, flexible] animated:false];
```

This assumes you have the toolbar showing through your navigation controller (to show it from any View Controller that's shown by a navigation controller, `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];`)

It looks something like this (iOS 9):
[image: UILabel in a UIBarButtonItem with a custom view]

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. Gave you 10 points bonus (on other answer).

Answer (score 1):

**UIToolbar** doesn't have a title property. As others suggested you need to add a **UILabel** as a title.

Or you can use **UINavigationBar** instead and initialize using `- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift 2.2 implementation of Aaron Ash's answer

```
let toolbarLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
toolbarLabel.text = "Text in yo toolbar"
toolbarLabel.sizeToFit()
toolbarLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
toolbarLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
toolbarLabel.textAlignment = .Center
let labelItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: toolbarLabel)
let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target:nil, action:nil)
self.setToolbarItems([flexible, labelItem, flexible], animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift 3 implementation:

```
    let topBarTitleLabel = UILabel.init(frame: (CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: 0.0))))
    topBarTitleLabel.text = "Text in yo toolbar"
    topBarTitleLabel.sizeToFit()
    topBarTitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    topBarTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    topBarTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    let topBarButtonItemTitleLabel = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: topBarTitleLabel)
    let flexibleBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.topToolBar.setItems([flexibleBarButtonItem, topBarButtonItemTitleLabel, flexibleBarButtonItem], animated: false)
    self.topToolBar.setNeedsLayout()
```